# Refactoring. Loading data in RecyclerView with MutableState from ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have sealed class State and I need to load data from `data class Loaded<T>` to RecyclerView in Fragment. How to correctly observe state in fragment and load it to RecyclerView? The main problem, that data is generic.

```
sealed class State {
    object Success : State()
    object Waiting : State()
    object Loading : State()
    data class Loaded<T>(val data: T) : State()
    class Error(val message: String) : State()
    class TokenError(val message: String) : State() 
}
```

I've tried to use this code and it works fine, but I get warning **Unchecked cast** for
`val resorts = state.data as List<Resort>`
`roads as List<Route>`

```
override fun initFlow(){
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.state.collect { state ->
            when (state) {
                State.Waiting -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                }
                State.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
                }
                State.Success -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                }

                is State.Loaded<*> -> {
                    if (state.data is List<*>
                        && state.data.all { item -> item is Resort }
                    ) {
                        val resorts = state.data as List<Resort>
                        addResortsOnMap(resorts)
                    }

                    if (state.data is List<*>
                        && state.data.all { item -> item is Route }
                    ) {
                        val roads = state.data
                        roadsAdapter.setData(roads as List<Route>)
                    }
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                }

                is State.Error -> {
                    binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        state.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

                is State.TokenError -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), state.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.login)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to check in **when**, but it doesn't compile my app. I get error: `Cannot check for instance of erased type:`

`is State.Loaded<List<Resort>> -> {}`

Comment: Why are you using generic type in the first place?

Comment: @Steyrix I wanted to create general State class which I use with all fragments. So State.Loaded should have different types inside.

Comment: It is wrong way to design state. Usually states are consistent and simple, and different views use different data types and therefore states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check type using `when` operator, because types are erased at compile time and are substituted with `Any`. So during runtime, upon `when` gets executed, types are no longer known.

If you want to get rid of "unchecked cast" warning, you can use `as?`:

`val resorts = state.data as? List<Resort>`

However in this case, you should handle possible failure during cast, which will result in `resorts` being assigned with null value.

My suggestion is to rethink your state design. Generic list in `State` makes the architecture complicated, since you will be forced to implement type determining logic. I suppose you are trying to reuse one view for representing different data types, however at some point in your application flow you **should** know, what data you want to present.

What I would do is to define two different states.

```
class ResortListState : State() {
    val data: List<Resort>
}

class RouteListState : State() {
    val data: List<Route>
}
```